# Show jQuery custom content scroller only if necessary

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I am using [THIS](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) jQuery plugin to style the scrollbars in my site. All is working fine, but the problem is that the scroller is visible always even if is not necessary.

So my question is - how to hide it if is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Could You paste some of your code? Couse you must have been doing something wrong. Just edit those demos (http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html) and remove some paragraphs with text - scrollers disappear automatically if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set
autoHideScrollbar: true,
In your plugin options to hide the scrollbar when not in use.

Example:

```
$("#cs_content").mCustomScrollbar({
autoHideScrollbar: true,    
//other plugin options
});
```

If you need a demo for this check out -http://bitconfig.com/custom-content-scroller/bitconfig_custom_content_scroller.html

Set the "Autohide scrollbar" checkbox and then watch the live preview of it.

- Patrick